# Runtime Errors using android studio boilerplate code for GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I'm having trouble with running a basic google maps demo on an emulator (Pixel 4 API 30). Sometimes it works but other times I get one of two errors. I've set up the API key using [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start#None-kotlin) guide as opposed to just putting it in the google_maps_api.xml provided in the base code.

###### manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.joe.googlemapsdemo">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the "MyLocation" functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GoogleMapsDemo">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

###### activtiy_maps.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

###### MapsActivity.kt

```
package com.joe.googlemapsdemo

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import com.joe.googlemapsdemo.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val osaka = LatLng(34.677518,135.3459511)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(osaka).title("Marker in Osaka"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(osaka))
    }
}
```

Error message one

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.joe.googlemapsdemo, PID: 10408
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.joe.googlemapsdemo/com.joe.googlemapsdemo.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.joe.googlemapsdemo:layout/activity_maps: Binary XML file line #9 in com.joe.googlemapsdemo:layout/activity_maps: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.joe.googlemapsdemo:layout/activity_maps: Binary XML file line #9 in com.joe.googlemapsdemo:layout/activity_maps: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.joe.googlemapsdemo:layout/activity_maps: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070016 type #0x3 is not valid
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDimensionPixelSize(Resources.java:827)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ax.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213016100@21.30.16 (150700-0):5)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fh.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213016100@21.30.16 (150700-0):6)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bo.az(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213016100@21.30.16 (150700-0):16)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cr.o(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213016100@21.30.16 (150700-0):2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.o.aX(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213016100@21.30.16 (150700-0):22)
        at dx.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@213016100@21.30.16 (150700-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zza(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzj.onCreateView(Unknown Source:29)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source:29)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zad.zaa(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreateView(Unknown Source:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source:28)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:386)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.joe.googlemapsdemo.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(ActivityMapsBinding.java:36)
        at com.joe.googlemapsdemo.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(ActivityMapsBinding.java:30)
        at com.joe.googlemapsdemo.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.kt:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Error message two

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 688 
Process: com.joe.googlemapsdemo, PID: 8853 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference 
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):11) 
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):3) 
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.g.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):23) 
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bt.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):20) 
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.av.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):56)
```

I'm not changing anything to get different error messages which is very confusing, what's even more confusing is that sometimes it will work. I tried relocating my API key to the google_maps_api.xml and wiping the data from my emulator. I have seen similar problems to this but no solutions seem to match/work.

Comment: Any updates on this topic? I'm constantly receiving your second message... and somehow it triggers a segmentation fault when restarting app

Comment: Not on my side I'm afraid.

Comment: I created an issue in google, i will leave link here in case of further advances in regarding this situation, hope this helps: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201308676

Answer (score 0):

In activit_maps.xml, try changing:
com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
to
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've seen posts where the inverse of this is the issue. I doesn't seem to resolve anything though, I still just get error message one.